# How many available IPv6 multicast prefixes are there?

Tags: ipv6, multicast

How many freely available multicast prefixes are there?
The RFC specifies every ff00::/8 as the required prefix. Accordingly, there are 16*16 = 256 multicast prefixes. However, a large part are already taken (e.g., ff02::2  ).

So how many are there actually available?

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense... there's no concept of "prefixes" in IPv6 multicast.  [The base RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291) defines an IPv6 multicast address as looking like this:

```
|   8    |  4 |  4 |                  112 bits                   |
+------ -+----+----+---------------------------------------------+
|11111111|flgs|scop|                  group ID                   |
+--------+----+----+---------------------------------------------+
```

This means that, within each [multicast scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7346), there are only 2^112 (5,192,296,858,534,827,628,530,496,329,220,096) multicast groups available (not many, but I'm sure you'll agree it's significantly more than 256).

There are a few "well-known" multicast addresses are available in [an IANA-managed register](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml).  There are also ways to generate [source-specific multicast addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4607).

Of course, in proper IPv6 style, all of this is complicated somewhat with [various options and flags](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7371), however all of the addressing schemes described therein provide 2^32 (about four billion) multicast group IDs per unicast /64 (typically called "a subnet" in IPv6).  I think that should be enough for anyone in the nearish future.

Comment: What I mean is, in theory you with ffxx you have 256 available multicast addresses, discounting the group ID. But, for instance, ff02 is reserved for Link-local addresses. So, discounting those, how many ffxx are truly available?

Comment: No, there is a maximum of 256 available combinations of flags and scopes. Each of those has 2^112 available addresses. Which flags and scope to use (the xxx part) depends on what you want and what the RFCs specify.

Comment: `ff02::/16` isn't "reserved for link-local addresses", it's the link-local *multicast scope*.  A very, very different thing.  The question "how many ffxx are truly available" is a question that I cannot make any sense out of.  Available for *what*?  Does it even make any sense to "count" them, and treat them as fungible, given that each combination of flags and scope has a distinct and very different meaning?

Comment: Available in the sense that they are not used for anything else. For example, FF3E is used for nothing (as far as I know), while FF02 is,

Comment: None are "available".  At best, they're "unassigned".  Use IPv6 multicast the way it was designed.